# D3Js button onclick with data as parameter doesnt work in .html()

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want my button, which is created via .html in D3Js to call a `fillTable` function and give it d (data) as parameter. The problem is, in my example below, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined`.

```
           d3.select("#test")
                    .selectAll("div")
                    .data(myData)
                    .enter().append("div")
                    .attr("class", "process")
                    .html(function (d, i) {
                        if (typeof d === 'object') {
                            console.log(d);
                            let processHtml = "<button title='Process settings' onclick = 'fillTable(d)' class='btn'></button>"
                         }
                   return processHtml
                     )}


function fillTable(data) {
   console.log(data)
}
```

I already tried to change processHTML to:

```
let processHtml = "<button title='Process settings' onclick = 'process.fillComponentTable('" + d + "')' class='btn'></button>"
```

Result is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

fillTable(" + JSON.stringify(d) + ")'